# ExtJS FormPanel in a FormPanel fails with "this.body is null"

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a rather complicated setup which I have boiled down to the code below.  I have an outer **FormPanel**, where I am trying to include a component that is a sub-class **FormPanel**.  In FF it is causing a "this.body is null" error.

Is this happening to anyone else?  Is it possible to get this to work?  I very much do not want to have to touch the subclass if I don't have to.

```
var test = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'test',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [{
      // this is where the subclass of FormPanel goes
      xtype: 'form',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Testing'
      }]
    }]
  }]
});
test.show();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your exact issue, but I do know you are never supposed to embed an xtype: 'form' into an xtype: 'form'. If you need its layout functionality then instead of xtype: 'form', use xtype: 'panel' with layout: 'form'.

Comment: A question of a question, but why aren't you supposed to use a xtype: 'form' in an xtype: 'form'?  I understand that it doesn't make much sense in terms of HTML, but as far as javascript is concerned they are just objects.

Comment: When the script is rendered into the HTML, you'd essentially have:

<form><form></form></form>

Comment: Thank you a million times over. Just lost over an hour to this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to embed a FormPanel inside another FormPanel.  This will not work.  I think what you want is this:

```
var test = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'test',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Testing'
    }]
  }]
});
test.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work if you added something (f.e. hidden textfield) into first 'form'.

Answer (score 0):

Extjs doesn't stop you from needing to understand HTML. You can't have nested forms.